# Query Store - What are the Security permissions needed to view reports?

Tags: sql-server-2016, query-store

Query store is enabled on 2 of our production databases but I no longer have access to see the Query Store node under the database since my SA privileges were revoked (I had them temporarily for a new server).

I can't find anywhere that describes what minimum permissions are needed for access to query store reports.

Comment: [Does this help](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ivandonev/permissions-required-to-run-query-store-in-sql-server-2016/)?

Comment: Yes, that's the ticket ;-)

Comment: @ErikDarling The link is broken. Could you please post the author name and article name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use

```
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO [USER];
```

Comment: Source? I presume it's in the docs somewhere.